# Jstree not displaying tree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am trying to populate a div with a jstree using json. The div, before the attempted population looks like this:

```
    <div id="mainTree">

    </div>
```

The jsonTree variable, which holds the tree, looks like this (as a string. The code passes the original json object):

```
"{\"core\":{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"123323\",\"parent\":\"#\",\"text\":\"123323\"},{\"id\":\"54366\",\"parent\":\"#\",\"text\":\"54366\"},{\"id\":\"634766\",\"parent\":\"#\",\"text\":\"634766\"}]}}"
```

The tree is populated like this:

```
$('#mainTree').jstree(jsonTree);
```

After the script the div looks like this, so the content is not there. What is wrong?

```
<div class="treeContainer" id="treeContainer">
        <input class="treeSearch" id="treeSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="">
        <div tabindex="0" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default jstree-leaf" id="mainTree" role="tree" aria-busy="false" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-activedescendant="j1_loading"><ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group"></ul></div>
    </div>
```

**Edit: Trying to populate the tree directly, with an example from jstree, does not work either. The population is done in a separate file, which is imported into index.html (last on the page).**

```
    $('#mainTree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': [
                { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
                { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
                { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
                { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" }
            ]
        }
    });
```

The index.html partially looks like this (where websocket-handling.js is what sets the mainTree).

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
    <script src="js/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/websocket-handling.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I see a # missing in the JQuery id selector, `$('mainTree')` should be `$('#mainTree')`

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. However, it is still has the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you included the jQuery library and the plugin? Any console errors?

Comment: Console outputs:
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.

Comment: Found it, it was in what I thought was customization of the tree (using another $("#mainTree").jstree({}) call, that actually overrode the original tree. Thanks for the help, it helped me to find it.